# curl works from within the private network, but Axios requests not working on browser

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs, express

I have a Red Hat Enterpise Linux 9 server hosted at a data center, which has an Apache web server and a MySQL installation. MySQL listens on 3306, and Apache on 80 (defaults).

I'm new to React and Express, and I'm testing a client-server app. I built the client side with create-react-app, and this is the code for App.js

**App.js**

```
import "./App.css";
import { useState } from "react";
import Axios from "axios";

function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [age, setAge] = useState(0);
  const [country, setCountry] = useState("");
  const [position, setPosition] = useState("");
  const [wage, setWage] = useState(0);

  const [newWage, setNewWage] = useState(0);

  const [employeeList, setEmployeeList] = useState([]);

  const addEmployee = () => {
    Axios.post("http://1.2.3.4:3001/create", {
      name: name,
      age: age,
      country: country,
      position: position,
      wage: wage,
    }).then(() => {
      setEmployeeList([
        ...employeeList,
        {
          name: name,
          age: age,
          country: country,
          position: position,
          wage: wage,
        },
      ]);
    });
  };



  const getEmployees = () => {
    Axios.get("http://1.2.3.4:3001/employees").then((response) => {
      setEmployeeList(response.data);
        console.log("retrieving the list");
        console.log(employeeList);
    });
  };


getEmployees();


  const updateEmployeeWage = (id) => {
    Axios.put("http://1.2.3.4:3001/update", { wage: newWage, id: id }).then(
      (response) => {
        setEmployeeList(
          employeeList.map((val) => {
            return val.id == id
              ? {
                  id: val.id,
                  name: val.name,
                  country: val.country,
                  age: val.age,
                  position: val.position,
                  wage: newWage,
                }
              : val;
          })
        );
      }
    );
  };

  const deleteEmployee = (id) => {
    Axios.delete(`http://1.2.3.4:3001/delete/${id}`).then((response) => {
      setEmployeeList(
        employeeList.filter((val) => {
          return val.id != id;
        })
      );
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="information">
        <label>Name:</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          onChange={(event) => {
            setName(event.target.value);
          }}
        />
        <label>Age:</label>
        <input
          type="number"
          onChange={(event) => {
            setAge(event.target.value);
          }}
        />
        <label>Country:</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          onChange={(event) => {
            setCountry(event.target.value);
          }}
        />
        <label>Position:</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          onChange={(event) => {
            setPosition(event.target.value);
          }}
        />
        <label>Wage (year):</label>
        <input
          type="number"
          onChange={(event) => {
            setWage(event.target.value);
          }}
        />
        <button onClick={addEmployee}>Add Employee</button>
      </div>
      <div className="employees">
        <button onClick={getEmployees}>Show Employees</button>

        {employeeList.map((val, key) => {
          return (
            <div className="employee">
              <div>
                <h3>Name: {val.name}</h3>
                <h3>Age: {val.age}</h3>
                <h3>Country: {val.country}</h3>
                <h3>Position: {val.position}</h3>
                <h3>Wage: {val.wage}</h3>
              </div>
              <div>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="2000..."
                  onChange={(event) => {
                    setNewWage(event.target.value);
                  }}
                />
                <button
                  onClick={() => {
                    updateEmployeeWage(val.id);
                  }}
                >
                  {" "}
                  Update
                </button>

                <button
                  onClick={() => {
                    deleteEmployee(val.id);
                  }}
                >
                  Delete
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The server is supposed to run on port 3001 of the same machine. The code for the server's index.js is below.

**index.js for server**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const mysql = require("mysql");
const cors = require("cors");

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

const db = mysql.createConnection({
  user: "apphost",
  host: "0.0.0.0",
  password: "password",
  database: "employeeSystem",
  insecureAuth: 'true'
});

app.get('/home', (req, res) => {
        res.send("HELLO THERE\n");

});

app.post("/create", (req, res) => {
  const name = req.body.name;
  const age = req.body.age;
  const country = req.body.country;
  const position = req.body.position;
  const wage = req.body.wage;

  db.query(
    "INSERT INTO employees (name, age, country, position, wage) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)",
    [name, age, country, position, wage],
    (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        res.send("Values Inserted");
      }
    }
  );
});



app.get("/employees", (req, res) => {
  db.query("SELECT * FROM employees", (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log('server index.js problem')
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.send(result);
    }
  });
});

app.put("/update", (req, res) => {
  const id = req.body.id;
  const wage = req.body.wage;
  db.query(
    "UPDATE employees SET wage = ? WHERE id = ?",
    [wage, id],
    (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        res.send(result);
      }
    }
  );
});

app.delete("/delete/:id", (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  db.query("DELETE FROM employees WHERE id = ?", id, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.send(result);
    }
  });
});

app.listen(3001, () => {
  console.log("Server running on port 3001.");
});
```

After running the server with `node index.js`, when I run `curl http://1.2.3.4:3001/employees` from a machine on the same physical network, I get a JSON output of the data in the MySQL database as expected. From my Windows CMD, a browser on my Windows machine, or from my phone, the request times out.

Keep in mind that I'm SSH-ing to the linux VM, while on a VPN provided by the data center.

This is the error I get on chrome:
`Uncaught (in promise) M {message: 'Network Error', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_NETWORK', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}`

Not sure what the issue is. Tried a lot of solutions from all over the internet, but nothing seems to work.

If any more information is needed, feel free to ask. I'll do anything to get this issue fixed and understand what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you find a solution to this problem? i ran into same thing with React native over corporate network vpn

Comment: @TheAmbidextrous For me the issue was that the port I was running the app on, wasn't publicly accessible. I asked the Server Management company to make it publicly available and it started working